# Absolutely continuous, integral, limit

Tags: functional-analysis, integration, limits

This is exercise from Folland (chapter 6. excercise 34.):

If f is absolutely continuous on $[\epsilon, 1]$ for $0<\epsilon<1$ and $\int_0^1 x|f'(x)|^p dx<\infty$, then:

- $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)$ exists (and is finite) if $p>2$,
- $\frac{|f(x)|}{|\log x|^{1/2}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ if $p=2$, and
- $\frac{|f(x)|}{x^{1-2/p}}\rightarrow 0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ if $p<2$.

---

I don't know how to start, and would appreciate some hints.

Answer (score 1):

You want to understand the behavior of $f(x)$ as $x\to 0$, knowing something about $f'$. It is natural to  begin with FTC and triangle inequality:
$$|f(x)|=\left|f(b)-\int_x^b f'(t)\,dt\right| \le |f(b)|+\int_x^b \left|f'(t)\right|\,dt \tag1$$

Then

> relate the integral on the right side of (1) to $\int_x^b t|f'(t)|^p dt$ using Hölder's inequality.

While doing so,

> you may have to decide whether to keep $b$ fixed (good enough for getting an upper bound on $|f|$) or to make it close to $0$ (may be able to get the Cauchy property, hence the existence of limit).

Comment: I'm trying to write it down but don't see how to deal with $1/p$ I get on $\left(\int t|f'(t)|^p dt\right)^{1/p}$ after applying Holder. Also why are there conditions on values of p?

Comment: @Ana All you know (and need to know) about $\int t|f'(t)|^p dt$ is that it's some finite number. The fact that it's raised to power $1/p$ is of no importance. If $C$ is a number you don't know, then $C^{1/p}$ is just another number you don't know. Well, perhaps in some cases you will choose $b$ small to make the integral small; then the integral to $1/p$ will be small too.... But the important integral is the other one that you get from Holder's inequality, with $|f'|$ and other things in it. The behavior of this integral depends on $p$.

Comment: I've thought about that but then I'm not doing the other integral right because i get this: $\int_{\epsilon}^1|f'(x)|dx \leq \int_0^1|f'(x)|dx=\int_0^1x^px^{1/p}|f'(x)|dx\leq \left(\int_0^1x^{pq}dx\right)^{1/q}\left(\int_0^1x|f'(x)|^pdx\right)^{1/p}$. Then I focus on $\int_0^1x^{pq}dx$, which is bounded if $p\cdot q=\frac{p-1}{p^2+p-1}>0$, but I don't get $p>2$??? Guess I'm doing something wrong?